# committing a single file using python-hglib

Tags: python, mercurial, hglib

I am trying to implement a rudimentary scm using python-hglib.
So far I have managed to connect to a repo (local) and I want to commit a single file among many.
I am not sure how to do this. Consider the following:

```
client = hglib.open(my_mercurial_repo)
root_repo=hglib.client.hgclient.root(client)
print "%s root" % root_repo
rev, node =client.commit('Simple commit message', addremove=False, user='user1')
```

This connects to *my_mercurial_repo* successfully, but when I get to the commit line I get this error:

> 'hglib.error.CommandError'>, CommandError('commit', '-m',
>   'Checkpoint', '-u', 'myself', '--debug')

However if I change it to:

> rev, node =client.commit('Simple commit message', addremove=True,
>   user='user1')

It works fine. Looking at the documentation, `addremove=True` would mark new/missing files as added/removed before committing.

So I guess my question is: how do I commit a single file in a repository of n files using python-hglib?

Just a quick update, thanks to @kAlmAcetA's response I updated my code as suggested to include

```
client.add('/tmp/repo/somefile')
rev, node =client.commit('Simple commit message', addremove=False, user='user1')
```

when I did this, the error goes away, the FIRST time commit is executed. 
If I execute the code again on the same file that I had opened I still get the error. 
So maybe what I am looking to do is to

- Open a file *(i'm ok with this)*
- Add some text to the file *(i'm ok with this)*
- Commit the file
- Add more text to the same file *(i'm ok with this)*
- Commit the file

I am now struggling to do the commit-->edit-->commit loop for a single file.

Regards

Comment: Today I discovered hglib (having used Mercurial basically since it started).  And I find I don't really want to use it.  I prefer software with some documentation, and hglib has basically none.  *Still*, in 2023.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first add that file to commit using [client's add method](http://www.selenic.com/repo/python-hglib/file/c62635b24826/hglib/client.py#l209).

```
...
client.add('/tmp/repo/somefile')
rev, node =client.commit('Simple commit message', addremove=False, user='user1')
...
```

You have to **add** file only for the very first time (on success you will get `True` otherwise `False`), next modifications requires only **commit**.

Note: If you would try to **add** the same file, unfortunately you will get `True` as well, then **commit** will fail with exception:

```
hglib.error.CommandError: (1, 'nothing changed', '')
```

Is good to wrap commit with `try...expect` probably.

Comment: Thanks, when I do client.add the error goes away, the FIRST time commit is executed, if I execute the code again on the same file that I had opened I still get the error. I have edited my question accordingly

Comment: you have to add file to repo only for the very first time, next modifications require only commit

Answer (score 2):

Committing a single file using hglib.commit is not supported, but you can use hglib.rawcommand, which uses the same syntax as hg on the command line:

```
repo = hglib.open(path_to_your_repository)
repo.rawcommand(args=['commit', 'filename'])
```

The first element in args must be an hg command name. The remaining elements are any options you'd use with that command. In my actual code, I have:

```
repo.rawcommand(['commit','-m '+commit_msg, file_name)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to commit a single file, no matter how many files in your working copy might have changed, just as if you’d do on the command line:

```
hg commit ${file}
```

hglib’s `commit` method does not seem to provide for this:

```
def commit(self, message=None, logfile=None, addremove=False, closebranch=False,
           date=None, user=None, include=None, exclude=None):
    """
    Commit changes reported by status into the repository.

    message - the commit message
    logfile - read commit message from file
    addremove - mark new/missing files as added/removed before committing
    closebranch - mark a branch as closed, hiding it from the branch list
    date - record the specified date as commit date
    user - record the specified user as committer
    include - include names matching the given patterns
    exclude - exclude names matching the given patterns
    """
```

**Committing just a single file doesn’t seem to be supported.**  `hglib` is supposed to wrap Mercurial’s commandline in some fashion, and the `hg` command *can* commit a single changed file, so this is weird.  Then again, the documentation is scarce to the point of being non-existent, so it’s unclear if that’s by design or not.

I’d file a bug for this.